# Pass data from detailed to master view? (UITableView) Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, segue

Sorry if the answer to this is obvious,

But I was wondering if anyone knew how to pass data from the detailed view to the master view of a UITableView system in swift using storyboards?

I have used `prepareForSegue()` to go from the master to the detailed view, but I don't think that that works when going from detailed to master. If it helps I'm working off the pre built "master-detail" template in Xcode.

Any help would be great appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There's a few approaches. It really depends what data you are trying to pass back. For example, if you're selecting a single item from a list, I'd define a delegate protocol for the detailViewController and have the master controller adopt it. Define a property for the delegate in detail, and set it in `prepareForSegue`:

`destinationViewController.delegate = self`

Then in the detail controller when the choice is made you just do `[delegate didChooseObject:object]` (Obj-C, sorry, I don't do Swift yet.)

Alternatively, if your detail controller is changing some value in a data structure, you probably want to have some sort of separated model object that both master & detail operate on. Pass the model object into detail in `prepareForSegue`. Use Key-Value Observing in master so that it knows what detail changed (if it cares).

A third option is to use a "completion block". Pass the block into detail, and have detail run the block with whatever data got picked.